# React npm installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image: The errors I’m getting]

I tried installing npm but it ain’t working… I want help. I’m a beginner.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.

Comment: You have a typo. The latest version of CRA is 5.0.1. You wouldn't normally specify a version anyway.

Comment: Since you are a new user, you may not know: PLEASE... on Stackoverflow do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error says "No matching version found for create-react-app@5.1.0"
Run "npm i -g create-react-app" instead and you will download the latest version of the library.

Comment: It didn’t work for me sir.